# How to use HuggingFace Inference endpoints for both tokenization and inference?

Tags: huggingface-transformers, huggingface-tokenizers, huggingface

I am trying to set up separate endpoints for tokenization and inference using HuggingFace models. Ideally I would like to use HuggingFace inference endpoints.

Is there a straightforward way to spin up endpoints for encoding, decoding, and inference for the same HF model? Or would I need to create containers for the encoder/decoder myself? I know HF has inference endpoints, but I'm not sure how well supported the tokenizer use case is or how I would implement that (e.g. what does the post request look like for encoding vs decoding, can I run it on the same infra as the inference endpoint, etc).

I have tried HF inference endpoints for inference, and I see that there are tokenizers available, but I am not sure how I can implement encoder/decoder for the tokenizer using the inference endpoint, and I'm unsure how to optimize.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do what you want by creating a custom handler for an inference endpoint. Have a look at [custom handlers](https://huggingface.co/docs/inference-endpoints/guides/custom_handler) documentation.

You should also be able to run the encoder, decoder, and inference on the same inference endpoint by following the example [here](https://www.philschmid.de/multi-model-inference-endpoints). You would pass an argument to the endpoint e.g.:

```
{
  "inputs": "It is so cool that I can encode, decode, and infer on the same endpoint.",
  "function": "encode"
}
```